# Excel - Adding .0 at the end of each value in a Column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I Have the below sort of values in an Excel Column. I want to add .0 at end of each value which is a whole number

1.4

2

2.9

1544

3.6

5

Expected-outPut

1.4

2.0

2.9

1544.0

3.6

5.0

Comment: You don't need a formula. Just format the cells such that they show a single decimal.

Answer (score 0):

If you format all values as number it will give you two digits. You can then change that to a single digit. This can be done via the [Ribbon](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/available-number-formats-in-excel-0afe8f52-97db-41f1-b972-4b46e9f1e8d2).